# How/which pivot table component works with neo4j

Tags: neo4j, pivot-table

Advice needed on approaches/steps needed to represent a neo4j data source using a pivot table using JavaFX GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody has written a pivot table for JavaFX.  You could write one yourself, but it would be non-trivial.

You would likely be best off using an existing pivot table implementation such as the [Swing pivot table from JideSoft](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/pivot.htm).

Regardless of which UI component you use, you will probably need to write your own adapters to interface between neo4j and the UI component.

If you used a JavaFX [TableView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm) as a basis of a pivot table implementation, then you might create a neo4j data convertor for the [jfxdata](http://www.javafxdata.org/) project which allowed you to interface with your pivot table.